# Should I ignore SCSS?

Tags: ruby, sass

I consider myself and excellent CSS writer. Lately, I have had some requests to code in SCSS. However, I don't run Ruby in my environment and am weighing whether I should deal with that overhead. And yes, I know there are some work arounds to compile the SCSS.

So, should I go out of my way to learn and support SCSS, or should I consider it strictly a Ruby gem that has nothing to do with what I do?

Further, since most of my work runs goes on LAMP environments, what is the utility unless I have a client running Rails?

Comment: Too subjective - try programmers.stackexchange.com, or reddit, for a lively discussion.

Comment: Ok, you closed my question. Is there no proper venue for it?

Comment: Leonid, how is my question materially different than this one of yours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93540/your-attitude-to-haml

Comment: @Quentin has asked 2 questions total. How does that make him qualified to judge my question?

Comment: @mmcglynn — Proper venue: See the first comment. Leonid's question: It was asked 4 years ago when the question policy was different. Me: I've answered over 6000 of the things.

Comment: @mmcglynn It's really an interesting question, but this is not the place for it. Here's a discussion about SCSS and variants: http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/rvbyo/do_you_using_less_sass_or_stylus_what_are_your/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not that different, and there are [online converters](http://cssconvert.mgwebsolutions.net/) that can do the work for you. I would say that you should go for it.

Comment: I guess my question is more about changing my development environment than it is about learning something new. That said, I don't want to learn something that is not widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think scss is a lot better then css. You can write your css file very easy.

Take a look at the website of Sass, there are a lot of examples which are making you writing css much more easier. When you take a look at these, you will see that too.

Here is the link: [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) to the website.

My opinion: go for it!

Answer (score -2):

I also consider myself a fairly proficient CSS (writer? coder?). I've thrown SCSS out the window because I don't see the benefit. Honestly I just don't really understand what problem it solves.

I group it with the similar "coffee". My response to both of those (not necessarily directed towards you) is:

Listen, we don't need more abstraction. Learn Javascript, Learn CSS. You can take those skills with you. Pretty soon we'll just have a one-click button to build our yet-another-blog-system, pat ourselves on the back and call ourselves programmers.

Anyway, I like your thinking. I say flex your CSS muscles and stay in shape :)

Comment: nothing wrong coding everything by hand. I myself also do this in small projects. However when having really huge projects, you don't want to miss the power of those tools once you got into it.

Comment: -1. What about for those of us working on actual non-prefab applications? Perhaps even larger applications?